# Crawling the taxonomy store using a timer job in central admin

Tags: 2010, taxonomy, timer-jobs

I am trying to get a timer job to crawl the Taxonomy Termstores, and am having a problem determining which SPSite object to use when instantiating the TaxonomySession.  Is there a SPSite instance that identifies the Central Admin site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give you the site collection for Central Admin:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.Sites[0];
```